# Can setFixedSize be used on a surface inside of a RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-ndk, android-fullscreen

I'm trying to use setFixedSize to speed up a game on tablets with very large screen sizes as per http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2013/09/using-hardware-scaler-for-performance.html

The problem I'm running into is I currently have a RelativeLayout that I add my Surface to.

As a test case, I took the gl2jni NDK sample app and added a call to getHolder().setFixedSize(128,128) into GJ2JNIView.java in the init method.  That properly created a ugly 128x128 buffer that was scaled up to full screen and worked exactly as I expected.

Then I modified the onCreate method in JL2JNIActivity as follows.

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    mView = new GL2JNIView(getApplication());

    boolean useRelativeLayout = false;
    if ( useRelativeLayout ) {
      mLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      mLayout.setLayoutParams(param);
      mLayout.addView(mView);

      setContentView(mLayout);
    } else {
      setContentView(mView);
    }
}
```

When I set useRelativeLayout to false, and setContentView directly uses my GL2JNIView that called setFixed size, it works as expected.

When I set useRelativeLayout to true, it displays the mView as a small 128x128 buffer in the top left.

Answer (score 1):

So after looking into it, I was not setting my layoutParams on mView.

By setting layout params on my mView to the following, it properly scaled the mView

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

mView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```